# How to setup same post slug for different categories?

Tags: plugins, permalinks

how can i setup same post slug for different categories. i mean

www.example.com/author/physics
www.example.com/subject/physics

but in wordpress it shows

www.example.com/author/physics
www.example.com/subject/physics-2

how to solve this issue with code or plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check this code or download and install this plugin:
https://github.com/GaryJones/allow-duplicate-slugs
I hope it help you much.